# 64bit memory address won't fit in Win32(64?)'s API WriteProcessMemory?

Tags: windows, winapi, memory, 64-bit

Alright, so I'm trying to do the old hack the calculator tutorial here:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0zPwg4iUDk
But give it my own spin by adding a form and a button to inject the new value into the calculator. But it keeps spitting out the "can't write to memory" error. Now I dunno why, but I think it's cause my memory address I'm trying to write is from a 64 bit OS. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

#define IDBUTTON 102

//prototypes
void injectValue();

using namespace std;

/*  Declare Windows procedure  */
LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND, UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM);

/*  Make the class name into a global variable  */
char szClassName[ ] = "CodeBlocksWindowsApp";
HINSTANCE g_hInst;
int newValue = 500;

int WINAPI WinMain (HINSTANCE hThisInstance,
                     HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     LPSTR lpszArgument,
                     int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND hwnd;               /* This is the handle for our window */
    MSG messages;            /* Here messages to the application are saved */
    WNDCLASSEX wincl;        /* Data structure for the windowclass */

    /* The Window structure */
    g_hInst = hThisInstance;
    wincl.hInstance = hThisInstance;
    wincl.lpszClassName = szClassName;
    wincl.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;      /* This function is called by windows */
    wincl.style = CS_DBLCLKS;                 /* Catch double-clicks */
    wincl.cbSize = sizeof (WNDCLASSEX);

    /* Use default icon and mouse-pointer */
    wincl.hIcon = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hIconSm = LoadIcon (NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
    wincl.hCursor = LoadCursor (NULL, IDC_ARROW);
    wincl.lpszMenuName = NULL;                 /* No menu */
    wincl.cbClsExtra = 0;                      /* No extra bytes after the window class */
    wincl.cbWndExtra = 0;                      /* structure or the window instance */
    /* Use Windows's default colour as the background of the window */
    wincl.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) COLOR_BACKGROUND;

    /* Register the window class, and if it fails quit the program */
    if (!RegisterClassEx (&wincl))
        return 0;

    /* The class is registered, let's create the program*/
    hwnd = CreateWindowEx (
           0,                   /* Extended possibilites for variation */
           szClassName,         /* Classname */
           "Calculator Trainer",       /* Title Text */
           WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW, /* default window */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* Windows decides the position */
           CW_USEDEFAULT,       /* where the window ends up on the screen */
           544,                 /* The programs width */
           375,                 /* and height in pixels */
           HWND_DESKTOP,        /* The window is a child-window to desktop */
           NULL,                /* No menu */
           hThisInstance,       /* Program Instance handler */
           NULL                 /* No Window Creation data */
           );


    /* Make the window visible on the screen */
    ShowWindow (hwnd, nCmdShow);

    /* Run the message loop. It will run until GetMessage() returns 0 */
    while (GetMessage (&messages, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
        /* Translate virtual-key messages into character messages */
        TranslateMessage(&messages);
        /* Send message to WindowProcedure */
        DispatchMessage(&messages);
    }

    /* The program return-value is 0 - The value that PostQuitMessage() gave */
    return messages.wParam;
}


/*  This function is called by the Windows function DispatchMessage()  */

LRESULT CALLBACK WindowProcedure (HWND hwnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    HWND hwndButton;
    switch (message)                  /* handle the messages */
    {
        case WM_COMMAND:
          if(((HWND)lParam) && (HIWORD(wParam) == BN_CLICKED)){
            switch(LOWORD(wParam)){
              case IDBUTTON:{
                   injectValue();
                   break;
              }
              default:
                   break;
            }
          }
          break;


        case WM_CREATE:
           hwndButton = CreateWindowEx(0,                    /* more or ''extended'' styles */
                     TEXT("BUTTON"),                         /* GUI ''class'' to create */
                     TEXT("Inject Value"),                        /* GUI caption */
                     WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,   /* control styles separated by | */
                     10,                                     /* LEFT POSITION (Position from left) */
                     10,                                     /* TOP POSITION  (Position from Top) */
                     200,                                    /* WIDTH OF CONTROL */
                     30,                                     /* HEIGHT OF CONTROL */
                     hwnd,                                   /* Parent window handle */
                     (HMENU)IDBUTTON,                        /* control''s ID for WM_COMMAND */
                     g_hInst,                                /* application instance */
                     NULL);
           break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage (0);       /* send a WM_QUIT to the message queue */
            break;

        default:                      /* for messages that we don't deal with */
            return DefWindowProc (hwnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }

    return 0;
}

void injectValue(){
    cout << "button pushed" << endl;

    HWND chwnd = FindWindow(0, "Calculator");
    if(chwnd == 0)
        cerr << "HWND not found!" << endl;

    else{
        DWORD pID;
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(chwnd, &pID);
        HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, pID);

        if(!hProc)
            cerr << "Can't open hProc!" << endl;

        else{
            int success = WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (LPVOID) 0xA4283C508C, &newValue, (DWORD_PTR) sizeof(newValue), NULL);

            if(success > 0)
                cout << "wrote to memory" << endl;

            else
                cerr << "Can't write to memory" << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that 0xA4283C508C is correct? Maybe first check if you can read from it and then write something new. And if you want to write to 64-bit process then I think you should compile your app in 64-bit mode so you can operate on large pointers.

Comment: yeah, the address is correct. Also I'm using code::blocks. How would I compile my program in 64bit mode?

Comment: You need to have 64-bit mingw or 64-bit version of Visual Studio (from Windwos SDK 7.1 for example).
If your Calculator is 64-bit version this address if for sure wrong.
CheatEngine used in this example are working on 32-bit version of Calculator so pointer is 4 bytes long while for 64-bit OS you need to find pointer that is 8 bytes long. I'm not sure if CheatEngine works with 64-bit apps so it will be hard for you to find this pointer.

Comment: CheatEngine 6 and up have 64-bit support. Also, it's very likely that calc.exe supports ASLR so its imagebase can change on every reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, whenever you have problems with WINAPI, you should use `GetLastError` to find the * specific* error.

In this case, I'm pretty sure you lack debug privileges, so the OS is denying write permissions, see [AdjustTokenPrivilages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375202%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa446619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) example, you want `SE_DEBUG_NAME` privilege.

However, it should be noted that you should never use a fixed virtual address (`0xA4283C508C` in your case), as most programs will be relocated,
invalidating your address (either due to ASLR, code page overlaps or jsut a pure lack of a preferred load address)

Comment: You only need debug privilege to open handles to processes that run under a different user.

Comment: @pezcode: no, you need it to open handles to programs that require administrative or debug privileges (or anything else you don't have the privileges to currently access), this is why ring3 debuggers are required to run in admin mode, so they can access protected process memory. maybe you should read up on access control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa374860(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: ring3 debuggers work on non-admin accounts just fine, as long as you don't try to attach to a process of another user (that includes SYSTEM). If you had browsed that link yourself, you would have found this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb530716%28v=vs.85%29.aspx And another one: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/131065/en-us